# How to close modal window when layer unchecked from control

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I have a modal window that pops up when a user checks a layer from a menu. The user can close this modal window by pressing the "X" icon on the window or clicking on the map. **However, when the user unchecks the layer from the menu, the modal will popup again.**

I need help writing the code so the modal will not popup again when the user unchecks the layer from the menu.

*Note: I am using Leaflet for the map and Bootstrap for the modal.*

Here's my hypothetical code:

HTML for the modal:

```
<div id="myRouteModal">blah blah</div>
```

HTML for the custom layers menu:

```
<label><input id="myRoute" type="checkbox" class="check">My Route</label>
```

JS for custom menu control:

```
var overlaysMenuCtrl = L.Control.extend({ ... blah blah... });

map.addControl(new overlaysMenuCtrl)());
```

JS:

```
function toggleLayer(checked, layer){
    if(checked){
        map.addLayer(layer);
    } else {
        map.removeLayer(layer);
    }
}

$(".check").change(function(){
    var layerClicked = $(this).attr("id");
//Turn layers on and off based on the ID of the radio checked
   switch(layerClicked){
    case "myRoute": toggleLayer(this.checked, myRoute);
        $('myRouteModal').modal(modalOptions);
    break;
    ...and other layers ...
}
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code:

```
switch(layerClicked){
    case "myRoute": toggleLayer(this.checked, myRoute);
        $('myRouteModal').modal(modalOptions);
```

You call the `$('myRouteModal').modal(modalOptions);` every time. Instead, you have to test, if the clicked checkbox is checked. Only if the checkbox is check, you should call the `.modal()`-function.

The correct code would be:

```
case "myRoute": toggleLayer(this.checked, myRoute);
    if(this.checked) {
        $('myRouteModal').modal(modalOptions);
    }
break;
```

Comment: do you mind providing an example? Can't quite get it working on my end.